# How can I log every time a user has logged in and logged out in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to log every time a user has logged in or logged out in Django. I am using the default login and logout views by Django. How can I implement logging these easily without the need for a model to store them? Only using logging also if possible that I can edit these default views in my views.py this can be much easier

My *views.py* code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import *
from .forms import *
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger('django')

def TransactionQuery(request):
        userAccounts = Account.objects.filter(Account_User = request.user).all()
        allTransactions = Transaction.objects.filter( Q(Transaction_From__in = [account.Account_ID for account in userAccounts]) | Q(Transaction_To__in = [account.Account_ID for account in userAccounts])).all()
        return allTransactions

def about (request):
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    print(ip)
    return render(request, 'website/about.html',{'title': 'About'})

def home (request):
    return render(request, 'website/home.html',{'title': 'Home'})

@login_required
def profile (request):
    return render(request, 'website/profile.html',{'title': 'Profile'})

@login_required
def dashboard (request):
    contex = {
    'accounts': Account.objects.filter(Account_User=request.user).all(),
    'transactions':TransactionQuery(request),
    'title': 'Dashboard'
    }
    return render(request, 'website/dashboard.html',contex)

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username1 = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            usr= User.objects.filter(username=username1).first()
            acc=Account(Account_User=usr)
            acc.save()
            logger.info(f'Account created for {username1}')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username1}! you can log in now')
            return redirect('login-page')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'website/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def transfer (request):
    accs1=[]
    accs=Account.objects.filter(Account_User=request.user)
    for acc in accs:
        accs1.append(str(acc.Account_ID))
    acc_dictionary =dict(zip(accs1,accs1))  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form= MoneyTransfer(request.POST,acc=acc_dictionary)
        if form.is_valid():
            from_acc = form.cleaned_data.get('from_account')
            to_acc = form.cleaned_data.get('to_account')
            check = Account.objects.all()
            amount = form.cleaned_data.get('amount')
            for i in check:
                if(i.Account_ID == to_acc):
                    acc1=Account.objects.filter(Account_ID=from_acc).first()
                    acc2=Account.objects.filter(Account_ID=to_acc).first()
                    acc1.Account_Balance -=amount
                    acc2.Account_Balance +=amount
                    acc1.save()
                    acc2.save()
                    trans = Transaction(Transaction_From = from_acc,Transaction_To = to_acc,Transaction_Amount = amount)
                    trans.save()
                    logger.info(f'transaction with amount:{amount} was made from: {acc1} to: {acc2}')
                    messages.success(request, f'Money Has Been Successfuly Transfered ')
                    return redirect('dashboard-page')
            logger.info(f'transaction faild! with amount: {amount} to Account: {to_acc} does not exist')
            messages.warning(request, f'transaction faild! Account: {to_acc} does not exist please enter a valid account')
            return render(request, 'website/transfer.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        form = MoneyTransfer(acc=acc_dictionary)
    return render(request, 'website/transfer.html',{'form':form})


#https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/get+user+ip+address+django
#getting ips from the user request
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to use a database, which is secure, fast, easily searchable/queryable, and easy to add a new entry to.

Comment: my website is developed for the purpose of testing see i am a cyber security analyst and only i need to test varius attacks against that website

Comment: so i need to store these actions in logs so it is easier for me sure later i can insert them into a module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Login and logout signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals): `user_logged_in`, `user_logged_out` and `user_login_failed` signals to do this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_login_failed, user_logged_out
from django.dispatch import receiver
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger('django')

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def post_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    logger.info(f'User: {user.username} logged in')

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def post_logout(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    logger.info(f'User: {user.username} logged out')

@receiver(user_login_failed)
def post_login_fail(sender, credentials, request):
    logger.info(f'Login failed with credentials: {credentials}')
```

Best would be to write this code in a file `signals.py` and in your apps `apps.py` add an import like:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
    
    def ready(self):
        import myapp.signals  # noqa
```

Comment: thank you for your answer can i ask if i wanted to add a login faild log how can i implement it knowing that i need to to log what was the username used in that faild login

Comment: @HamzahZabin there's also a `user_login_failed` signal added it to the answer.

Comment: thank you so much i really didn't know how to link my app to the signals.py code your answer was helpful to me

Comment: okay one more last question. can import models.py inside the signals.py file and then every time a log has been created i can store it inside the database am i correct ? like in my views.py code avove in the register view ?

Comment: @HamzahZabin yes you can, just make sure your models are loaded first, won't be any issue if they are in the same app in which you write these signals as your signals are loaded after the ready method is called.